# null with receipt data in angular $http

Tags: angularjs, json, http

This is my code:

```
 $scope.doLogin = function() {

    $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/user_signin",
            data: { username: $scope.user.username, password: $scope.user.password },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            responseType:'json'
        }).success(function (data) {
                console.log('data success');
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); 
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers,config){
          console.log('data error');
        });

};
```

Consol says:

> data success
>
> null

What I do wrong?
P.S.: API request is correct - I checked it in postman.

Answer (score 0):

You set responseType to 'json' make sure that your server side is also sending the response compatible to your format 'json'.

Or simply remove the response type check if it works